# TypeError at /videos/create_video/ expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

Hey guys how to provide the correct path of a video file after it is created in django for transcoding. I am getting an error specifying the error in path. I am quite new to this and not sure how to provide the correct path. This is the code I have for transcoding.

```
def encode_video(video_id):
    try:
        video = VideoPost.objects.get(id = video_id)
        input_file_path = video.file.path
        input_file_name = video.title

        #get the filename (without extension)
        filename = os.path.basename(input_file_path)

        # path to the new file, change it according to where you want to put it
        output_file_name = os.path.join('videos', 'mp4', '{}.mp4'.format(video.file))
        output_file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'videos', output_file_name)

        for i in range(1):
            subprocess.call([settings.FFMPEG_PATH, '-i', input_file_path, '-s', '{}'.format(16 /9), '-vcodec', 'mpeg4', '-acodec', 'libvo_aacenc', '-b', '10000k', '-pass', i, '-r', '30', output_file_path])

        video.file.name = output_file_name
        video.save(update_fields=['file'])
    except:
        raise ValidationError('Not converted')
```

tasks.py

```
@task(name= 'task_video_encoding')
def task_video_encoding(video_id):
    logger.info('Video Processed Successfully')
    return encode_video(video_id)
```

models.py

```
class VideoPost(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title               = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    height              = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    width               = models.PositiveIntegerField( editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    duration            = models.FloatField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    post_date           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Posted")
    updated             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Updated")
    slug                = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    file                = VideoField(width_field='width', height_field='height', duration_field='duration', upload_to='videos/')
    image               = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='videos/thumbnails/', verbose_name='Thumbnail image')
    format_set          = GenericRelation(Format)
```

view

```
class CreateVideoPostView(LoginRequiredMixin, BSModalCreateView):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = VideoPostForm()
        context = {
            'form':form,
        }
        return render(self.request, 'videos/video/create_video.html', context)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = VideoPostForm(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            video = form.save(commit=False)
            video.user = self.request.user
            video.save()
            task_video_encoding(video.id)
            return redirect('videos:my_video_home')
        else:
            raise ValidationError('Check all form fields.')
```

TRACEBACK:

```
    C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py in dispatch
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\danny\project\myproject\videos\views.py in post
            task_video_encoding(video.id) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\celery\local.py in __call__
        return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py in __call__
            return self.run(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\danny\project\myproject\videos\tasks.py in task_video_encoding
    return encode_video(video_id) …
▶ Local vars
C:\danny\project\myproject\videos\encoding.py in encode_video
        subprocess.call([settings.VIDEO_ENCODING_FFMPEG_PATH, '-i', input_file_path, '-s', '{}'.format(16 /9), '-vcodec', 'mpeg4', '-acodec', 'libvo_aacenc', '-b', '10000k', '-pass', i, '-r', '30', output_file_path]) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p: …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py in __init__
            self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child
                args = list2cmdline(args) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq): …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\os.py in fsdecode
        filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`. …
▶ Local vars
```

Can anyone provide a hint or the correct way to achieve this conversion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing i in the subprocess call

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221001/discussion-on-answer-by-ash123-typeerror-at-videos-create-video-expected-str).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you save it where you save all your static files. If you do not know what a static file folder is, it is where you add your css, images and videos. If you do not know how to create this folder visit the django documentation on static files here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: But this is to convert all videos uploaded by users not just a single video file.

Comment: You could use filters to decide which videos are converted and which are not, i am not too sure what you are asking

Comment: The problem is I am not able to encode any videos.. it is showing the error with video.path in encode function. Iam not sure whether its the right way to provide the path of a newly uploaded video.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of what video_id would be equal to?

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question with my createview.. video_id is taken after the video is saved. I dont know whether what I have done is correct. Please do have a look.

Comment: From what I can see, the error is that when you say video.path, their is no path variable in the VideoPost model, I think instead it should say os.path.realpath(video.file). I do not know if this will work for sure but os.path.realpath() is the way to find the path of a file and the file you are trying to find is for video.file.

Comment: It might not work as it is finding the path of something in the database

Comment: Instead of all of that you should just do:    output_file_name = os.path.join('videos', 'mp4', '{}.mp4'.format(video.file))

Comment: I used this instead
input_file_path = video.file.path and it worked but now I am getting another error regarding the subprocess. I will update the traceback I got. Please do have a look at it.